# Инициализация enum из кода

Tags: c#, unity3d, enum, unity3d-editor

Под инициализацией я подразумеваю создание `enum` из массива строк, например:

```
String[] enumPuncts;
enumPuncts=/*тут неважно откуда получаем данные*/;
//тут какието махинации какие етот массив строк превращает в enum
//чтобы код был примерно еквивалентен
/*
enum E{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
}
*/
```

Если это возможно, то покажите пример.
Если нет, то покажите реализацию подобного.
Это нужно для удобной настройки объектов в unity.

Comment: Даже если бы такое было возможно, кто во время выполнения код перепишет, чтобы это перечисление использовать?

Comment: Только через кастумный редактор [EditorGUILayout.Popup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html), но это не `enum`, а индекс с менами из массива на выбор.

Comment: @Yaroslav мне важен функционал и ето как раз даже может подойти но вроде у етой штуки нету множественного выбора который тоже нужен

Comment: В твоем вопросе нет описание того, что тебе нужно. Каждый твой следующий пост, утверждает что говорит о том что, предложенный вариант не годится потому, что ты хочешь что то еще. Напиши нормально, что тебе надо в итоге, во избежания расследования по хлебным крошкам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` — это набор констант. Константы определяются на этапе компиляции и не могут быть определены во время выполнения.

Самая ближайшая альтернатива — словарь, например:

```
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new();
settings["Alignment"] = "top";

if (settings.TryGetValue("Alignment", out string alignment))
{
    switch (alignment)
    {
        case "top":
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Его можно сериализовать в JSON, положить в `PlayerPrefs` и обратно.

Значением может быть необязательно строка, может быть число, или перечисление, или вообще что угодно. Зависит от потребностей.

---

*Я мог неверно понять вопрос, так как вы не уточнили как именно определяете сейчас и для чего нужно перечисление.*

Comment: желательно чтобы в инспекторе можно было делать все что и с enum а нужно чтобы менять список пунктов без изменения кода

Comment: @КарасёвАртемий инспектор работает до компиляции. Вы не сможете во время выполнения изменять состав перечисления, никак, это невозможно.